# Hello To print the second part of the code in reverse, for example, for the number 6, the output should be equal to the attached photo of this code

Tags: python

```
n=int(input("type a number:"))
for i in range(n+1):
a ='*'*i
print(a)
```

[This is the output for the number 6:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0BWw.jpg)

Comment: How would you solve it from a logical perspective?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like, using a little custom generator for the pyramid pattern:

```
def updown(n):
    yield from range(1, n)
    yield from range(n, 0, -1)

for i in updown(6):
    print(i * '*')


*
**
***
****
*****
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Thanks for
def updown(n):
    yield from range(1, n)
    yield from range(n, 0, -1)

for i in updown(n):
    print(i * '*')

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do it (and this doesn't feel too useful anyway), but this should work.

```
n=int(input("type a number:"))
i = 0
while i <= n:
    i+=1
    print("*"*i)
while i > 0:
    i-=1
    print("*"*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this

```
def pattern(n):
    return list(range(1, n+1)) + list(range(n-1, 0, -1))

>>> for i in pattern(6):
...    print(i * '*')
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```